# In Go, how do I check a value is of (any) pointer type?

Tags: pointers, reflection, go, go-interface

I have a slice of `interface{}` and I need to check whether this slice contains pointer field values.

Clarification example:

```
var str *string
s := "foo"
str = &s
var parms = []interface{}{"a",1233,"b",str}
index := getPointerIndex(parms)
fmt.Println(index) // should print 3
```

Comment: `*str` will dereference the pointer and it will be of nonpointer `string` type. Did you mean to put `str` into the slice literal?

Comment: yep, didn't noticed, edited.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use reflection ([`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package) to test if a value is of pointer type.

```
func firstPointerIdx(s []interface{}) int {
    for i, v := range s {
        if reflect.ValueOf(v).Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

Note that the above code tests the type of the value that is "wrapped" in an `interface{}` (this is the element type of the `s` slice parameter). This means if you pass a slice like this:

```
s := []interface{}{"2", nil, (*string)(nil)}
```

It will return `2` because even though 3rd element is a `nil` pointer, it is still a pointer (wrapped in a non-`nil` interface value).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, Thanks!